# What does the Crystal "Lockdown" power do?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I *finally* managed to obtain my first Crystal crew member (**finally!**). I note that he has a "Lockdown" power, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Crystal crew member with Lockdown power]

What does this power do? None of the tooltips I've seen provide any explanation. When is this power useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Lockdown: Active ability that coats the room they're in with crystals,
>   preventing anyone from entering or leaving and making the room itself
>   invincible to damage. The crystals wear off over time, or when
>   attacked. This ability requires time to recharge after being used.

[Source](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Races/Crew_Members)

Comment: Ack, beat me by 30 seconds :)

Comment: Yeah I saw that. And we had nearly identical posts

Comment: Ah well, I'll just have to be quicker next time :P.

Comment: BTW I think that wiki is outdated.  I definitely remember being able to attack and damage the room with my crew while they where in a locked down room.

Comment: @z- It says that you can attack the crystals, which will make the room vulnerable faster. Thats probably what you saw

Comment: @lawton nope.  I tped into their medbay activated lockdown and destroyed the medbay while the enemy was trying to get in.

Comment: @z OK, so it only protects your room? that's very useful information

Comment: Or maybe only protects against damage from outside the room (i.e. weapons)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to protect my own room from outside weapons.  I suspect that part just means it protects the *doors* from damage (which is true).

Answer (score 5):

The Crystal's Lockdown ability will block off a room with blue crystals, preventing damage & restricting movement by both friendly and enemy units.

From the [FTL wiki](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Races/Crew_Members):

> Lockdown: Active ability that coats the room they're in with crystals, preventing anyone from entering or leaving and making the room itself invincible to damage. The crystals wear off over time, or when attacked. This ability requires time to recharge after being used.